# How can I connect my Nokia Lumia 520 with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: usb, mount, nokia

I cannot seem find a way to connect a Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 14.04. I tried several solutions posted on the Internet, but I could not find the right one. Has someone achieved this?

Comment: have you used bluetooth connections too???

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your question to include exactly what you have tried and how it failed (including any relevant messages like errors, warnings, etc).

Answer (score 1):

The author of this project: [Android File Transfer For Linux](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux) luckily for me agreed to add WP8 support and now this is the only solution that reliable works, afaik.
Now it's able to connect my Lumia 1020 WP8.1 Denim and Kubuntu 15.04 via 
usb.

Of course, device shall be unlocked with correct PIN beforehand.

The project is a library and has simple GUI which is mostly for library demonstration and testing purposes, so don't blame it for UX.

Comment: I confirm this works even for my Lumia 730, which is only detected as PTP in 14.04 and later releases with the same libmtp version (I assume our devices will have been replaced when fixes for such devices make it out of the development tree into an OS release ヽ(◕﹏◕)ﾉ ). Good find and good job you did there.

Answer (score 0):

How to connect Lumia 520 Windows Phone (WP) (Windows 8.0 - Amber) to computer (Ubuntu 14.04):

1. Download Pocket File Manager (PFM) to WP from Store. PFM has a free version so no need to buy the full version within the app.
2. Turn on computer - do not enter password yet
3. Turn on phone - turn on pocket file manager
4. Connect phone to computer via USB
5. Enter computer password - computer is now fully on
6. Click phone icon launcher on computer
7. The phone and SD card will be displayed and file operations can be used in the normal way
8. Once tasks completed, keep the phone attached via USB and shut down the computer - Do NOT turn off computer file manager
9. Once the computer has shut down, remove phone USB

Notes:

1. If you do not use a password to open Ubuntu because you automatically  start the computer then turn on the phone, open PFM and connect the phone via USB before switching on the computer
2. Please note that the Cyan update (Windows 8.1) is imminent apparently. Cyan will have it's own file manager so PFM may not be necessary. Possibly the new file manager will mean that the current work around is superfluous too.

   1. Bluetooth works too as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer files between your computer and phone you can run a server and access it via the phone browser. I have started a project on github- [clouder-lite](https://github.com/rohithpr/clouder-lite/), give it a try!

PS: Python3 is available on Ubuntu14+ by default.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively to what nigel said, you may want virtualize windows in virtual machine if you have no access to the OS.
In fact this is quite a useful option to run programs like microsoft office, autocad and itunes; microsoft even made windows freely downloadable.

To do this you have to download virtualbox from the software center and then follow this tutorial: http://pclosmag.com/html/issues/201309/page15.html

Pay attention however to the fact that the license lasts only 90 days and then you have to restore the virtual machine from a snapshot or a backup.