# How to connect lumia 630 with ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mtp, nokia

I plugged my Windows Phone 8.1 device to Ubuntu 14.04. The OS is not detecting my phone.

Comment: Try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/631305/40581

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 1):

For my phone (Nokia Lumia 630 Dual SIM, WP 8.1) and Linux Mint 17.3 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) worked: try to connect it after you swiped the phone screen saver away. Or in other words: connect your phone just, when you see the Windows tiles on it (so you could start an app or do a call).

If I don't do so, my phone does not connect and my file browser just freezes.

Answer (score 0):

It will detect your device if you reboot your ubuntu 14.04 machine while your windows 8.1 device is plugged in.

Comment: it is not detecting even after reboot.

Comment: Try the steps from the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04 which may help you..