# How to connect Nokia Lumia 730 to Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: mtp, windows-phone

My Nokia Lumia 730 (WP8.1) is not getting detected on Ubuntu 15.04.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for a release which contains the patches for these devices in libmtp or use [android-file-transfer-linux](https://askubuntu.com/a/631305/40581).

---

Straight forward instructions:

> ## Building instructions
>
> ### Prerequisites
>
> - For ubuntu and other debian-based distros use the following command:
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libqt4-dev ninja-build libfuse-dev
>   ```
>
> …
>
> ### Building with ninja
>
> ```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake -G Ninja ..
> ninja
> ```
>
> Then run: `./qt/android-file-transfer`
>
> or…
>
> ## Installation
>
> ```
> sudo ninja install
> ```
>
> Then run: `android-file-transfer`

Comment: Thanks LiveWireBT for the solution. I have not tried it yet. I will give it a try today evening after office. I will let you know if android-file-transfer-linux worked for me or not.

Comment: I wanted to give a try to android-file-transfer-linux. But I ended up clueless about how to install it. Can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: @SatyajitPatnaik I added instructions to my post.

Comment: Thanks again @LiveWireBT. I will try this, this was there in the README file of the GIT repo. I was expecting a sudo apt-get install. Kind of lazy. :D

Comment: Tried this tool. Device did get detected, sometimes not. Works buggy. Didn't help much though.