# Can't mount Nokia Lumia 735 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mount, 15.04, sd-card, nokia

Description:
I connect  my Nokia Lumia 735 (WP8.1) via USB to Ubuntu (last updates all in) - it "mounts" "LUMIA 735" but suddenly with the popup error

"Impossibile montare "Lumia 735 (RM1038)"
Errore nell'inizializzare la fotocamera: -53: Could not claim the USB device"

In english: 
"Can't mount LUMIA 735 "(RM1038)"
Error in the photocamera initialisation -53 : Could not claim the USB Device"

and stop.... I can't see phone hdd nor  the SD card. And no programs or apps see nothing, actually (i.e. gmtp says "no device found").

SOMEONE KNOWS IS THERE A WAY to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Please note I've already read the literatur in regarding, and specially I've  read the answer in [How to connect Nokia Lumia 730 to Ubuntu 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640736/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-730-to-ubuntu-15-04) e.g. and installed all the packages required. But the same it doesn't work.

Luciano

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to mount my Nokia 735, and finally found the solution on a forum : you just have to connect the phone to the computer (error message) then restart the computer without unplugging the phone and after the restart you can now browse all your files on the Nokia (Phone memory, Sd Card)